# spring basic mvc sample application, annotation scan confusion

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations

Little confused, the basic spring mvc app has this:

app-config.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.samples.mvc.basic" />
```

and the mvc-config.xml has:

```
<!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

1. Do you really need both?
2. for component-scan, does this mean if I don't put the correct package path my @Controller and @Service markers will have no effect?
   **If I need more than one package, do I just duplicate the entry?**

I tried using just the mvc:annotation-driven but that didn't work, I had to put com.example.web.controllers in the component-scan xml node to make it work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*context:component-scan* is clear

> Scans the classpath for annotated components that **will be auto-registered as Spring beans**. **By default**, the Spring-provided @Component, @Repository, @Service, and @Controller stereotypes will be detected.

So @Controller is just a Spring bean. Nothing else.

And

*mvc:annotation-driven*

> registers the HandlerMapping and HandlerAdapter required **to dispatch requests to your @Controllers**

Which is similar to

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
```

**If I need more than one package, do I just duplicate the entry?**

You can if you want. *context:component-scan* **is just a bean post-processor**.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="br.com.app.view.controller"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="br.com.app.service"/>
```

Or

> Use a comma-separated list of packages to scan for annotated components.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="br.com.app.view.controller,br.com.app.service"/>
```

Comment: Just for curiosity: context:component-scan includes AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor and CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor which means means that the two components are autodetected and wired together - **all without any bean configuration metadata provided in XML**

Comment: Thanks, I didn't want to do br.com.app since it will be scanning potentially more classes than required. great answer!  btw what's the diff between a @component and @service ?

Comment: @Blankman None. @Service is also a @Component annotation. See here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html It is just a special metadata to **denote a service component in the service layer**.

Answer (score 1):

1. `mvc:annotation-driven` allows you to configure behavior of Spring MVC. See details in [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-annotation-driven) .For basic usage of Spring MVC you do not need it.
2. If you need more than one package just mention parent one: `<context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.samples.mvc" />`

Comment: so having mvc:annotation-driven is doing nothing?

Comment: No, `mvc:annotation-driven` allows you to configure behavior of Spring MVC. See details in documentation http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-annotation-driven

For basic usage of Spring MVC you do not need it.